# Node mocha array should contain an element

Tags: arrays, node.js, mocha.js, should.js

I want to do a simple assertion of something like

```
knownArray.should.include('known value')
```

The array is correct, but I simply can't figure out the proper assertion to use to check whether the array has this value (the index doesn't matter).  I also tried `should.contain` but both of these throw an error that `Object #<Assertion> has no method 'contain'` (or `'include'`)

How can I check that an array contains an element using `should`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Should.js](http://shouldjs.github.io/) has the [containEql](http://shouldjs.github.io/#assertion-containeql) method. In your case:

```
knownArray.should.containEql('known value');
```

The methods `include`, `includes` and `contain` you would find in [chai.js](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#include).

Comment: hi @rodrigo, how to equal two arrays in should?

Comment: @KoustuvSinha, it depends on what do you consider an equality between two arrays. Are they the same if all the elements are equal, but in a different order? Or does the order matter? This problem may be depper than you have considered. Take a look at [this queestion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript) or even in libraries like [LoDash](https://lodash.com/), which provides a lot of useful features, like the [isEqual](https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual) method. If that does not answer your question, ask a new question in SO, I'll be glad to discusss.

Answer (score 6):

[Mostly from the mocha docs](http://mochajs.org/#synchronous-code), you can do

```
var assert = require('assert');
var should = require('should');

describe('Array', function(){
  describe('#indexOf(thing)', function(){
    it('should not be -1 when thing is present', function(){
      [1,2,3].indexOf(3).should.not.equal(-1);
    });
  });
});
```

or if you don't mind not using should, you can always do

```
assert.notEqual(-1, knownArray.indexOf(thing));
```

Answer (score 0):

I like chai-things a lot:

https://github.com/RubenVerborgh/Chai-Things

It let's you do things like:

```
[{ a: 'cat' }, { a: 'dog' }].should.include({ a: 'cat' });
['cat', 'dog'].should.include('cat');
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this and is using chai, this is what I used based on docs for should/include

```
  it(`Should grab all li elements using double $$`, () => {
    const liEl = $$('ul li');

    const fruitList = ['Bananas', 'Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears'];

    liEl.forEach((el) => {
      expect(fruitList).to.include(el.getText());
    });
  });
```

I'm using webdriver.io, so you can ignore part where I'm grabbing the element, just included for completeness.